# Boundary condition for water waves generation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, boundary-conditions

I am trying to model water wave propagation in 2D with [CFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics). What would be a suitable boundary condition to generate the waves on the left boundary? Currently I vary the fraction of water above the initial water level as a sine of time. I get some results, but not too good so far. I also tried a dynamic mesh following a tutorial but results seem very hard to control.

Ideally I need a condition which would allow me to generate waves with desired characteristics (period, speed etc.)

I am doing it in [Fluent](http://www.ansys.com/Products/Simulation+Technology/Fluid+Dynamics/ANSYS+Fluent), so implementational advises are also appreciated as a bonus, but I guess the question isn't that much related to it. That's why I place my question here, not in the scicomp exchange.

Comment: Did you consider asking this question here: http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/fluent/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLEUNT has a open channel flow option for the VOF model, and a wave BC for open channel flow aswell. One can chose between several different formulations in the BC. The theoretical description can be found in the Theory Guide for FLUENT.

Comment: Is this intended to answer the question? It doesn't seem like it does, in which case it shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: I think it does, it gives a reference too look up the BCs setup, fluent's theory guide is incredibly thorough.